# difference between npm init and npm init --yes

Tags: npm, npm-init

I am new at node.js and don't quite understand what's the difference between
`npm init` and `npm init --yes`.

Could you help me out?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--yes means that any prompts will automatically be responded to as yes